# How do I test for ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED?

Tags: android, android-intent, junit, nfc

I have an Android activity that when in contact with an NFC tag calls a certain function. I would like to create tests for that.

In my test file, my logic is as follows:

```
// Create a ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED
// Respond to ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED
public void testNfc(){

}
```

In my code, I have a callback function "onNewIntent" which looks at the intent created when in proximity to an NFC tag:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) { ... }
```

But, in my test code, I cannot create an Intent of ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED. I looked at the class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

How do I create an `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` intent so I can test it? Somewhere along this line:

```
Intent nfcIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
if(nfcIntent == ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)
assertSomeMethod("functionWhichHandlesNFCTagDiscovered")
```

Thanks much!

Comment: "But, in my test code, I cannot create an Intent of ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED." Why, what happens if you do what you wrote?

Comment: That is pseudo code, Intent.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED does not exist.

Comment: Why do you want to test a mechanism thats already in Android? The intent dispatch system is there, and its working, what the reason for you to test it? And if you just want to test your method, then stub arround it as appropriate and call it from code (or simply use a physical device and a tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this: [ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.java#NfcAdapter.0ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)

I haven't tested it, but if you make an Intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
intent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG, "");
...
intent.putByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
//etc.
```

you may be able to do what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan a tag on a physical device - the emulator does not support NFC as far as I know.